# Replace for loop in R

Tags: r

I am new to this platform and I hope that someone can help me on this issue.
I need to replace the following *for loops* by some kind of *apply* functions since it runs much too slow.

```
X = dim(m)
Y_TFIDF = matrix(0, X[1], X[2])


for (i in 1 : X[1]) {

  maxNumTerms = which(m[i, ] > 0)
  docSize = sum(m[i, maxNumTerms])

   for (j in 1 : X[2]) { 

     if (m[i, j] > 0) {
       DF = length( m[ which(m[ ,j] > 0) ] )
       Y_TFIDF[i, j] = (m[i, j] / docSize) * log( X[1] / (1 + DF) )    
     }
     else {
       Y_TFIDF[i, j] = 0
     }
   }
 }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you think `apply` would be faster than a `for` loop?

Comment: hi, any other ideas ?

Comment: We can't really help you without a real example data and your desired output.

Comment: Hi, input is a document word matrix.  documents are rows, columns are occuring words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I read correctly your code, but maybe this could work:

```
 #creating a random m
 m<-matrix(runif(100*30,-1,1),nrow=100)
 docsize<-rowSums(m*(m>0))
 docsize[docsize==0]<-1
 res1<-m/docsize*log(nrow(m)/(1+rep(colSums(m>0),each=nrow(m))))*(m>0)
```

Following your code and creating `Y_TFIDF` it results:

```
 identical(res1,Y_TFIDF)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Seems to be correct, but there is some rows filled with NA now, which produces a FALSE in "identical()"

Comment: There are no NAs in matrix "m", so I wonder how they are produced ?

Comment: I performed several tests with different matrices and they all agreed on `res1` and `Y_TFIDF` being identical. Could you provide a small extract of your matrix that reproduce the issue?

Comment: Sure, where to put it ?

Comment: It seems that some rows have just 0 values and that leads to 0/0 operations and the `NaN` values. I edited my answer to solve this issue.